# Docker image wrapping for binary blobs

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

Is it possible to wrap random binary blobs into a Docker image?

Perhaps with a base layer of Alpine Linux so that the image consists of the blob as the top layer?

Comment: You can add arbitrary content to a docker image. If it is an executable, you will then want to set it to execute on startup or connect into docker after adding a shell to the image and run it manually once inside the image.

Comment: Are there any examples of adding arbitrary content to the docker image? Would this mean changing contents of the Dockerfile to regenerate it?

Comment: You can create a new Dockerfile that uses any desired image as its base. The FROM entry defined the starting image. Then you add COPY entries to copy whatever files into the image. What you do next depends on how you want to use the image.